# jQuery show element if not empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var agencyToolbar = $('#agency-header-toolbar');
if ($(":not(:empty)", agencyToolbar)) {
    agencyToolbar.show();
}
```

The code above works, but I wasn't sure if it's a proper way to use a jQuery selector.

Comment: Maybe you want to simply ask `if ($('#agency-header-toolbar')) { ...`

Comment: @zed: Your code will always result in "truthy". Same mistake as the original code. You probably meant to add `.length == 0` as in  `$('#agency-header-toolbar').length === 0` or `!$('#agency-header-toolbar').length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will always fire the `show` as `$(":not(:empty)", agencyToolbar)` creates a jQuery object which is never `null` so is always "truthy".

You wanted to use `is` (which returns a boolean result) like

```
if (agencyToolbar.is(':not(:empty))')){
```

or use a single selector like

```
$("#agency-header-toolbar:not(:empty)").show();
```

If you need it to be a tad faster, do the id selector first as its own operation, then filter it with `not()`

```
$("#agency-header-toolbar").not(":empty").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to select `#agency-header-toolbar` which are not empty. It is more simpler to use

```
var agencyToolbar = $("#agency-header-toolbar:not(:empty)");
agencyToolbar.show();
```